# knockout - issue with accessing a nested property

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-sortable

I'm trying to learn knockoutjs by studying existing sourcecodes and making small changes to them.. The source code that I'm trying to understand here is an example of knockout-sortable.js by RP Niemeyer.

The original example code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/UdXr4/)

I have made some small changes which are [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fzr4qfa8/8/)

The original code has a global property called maximumstudents which checked the number of students in each table. I have added a property in table called "maxstudents" which will decide how many students can sit in each table.

Also the original code enables each table is filled with students of both genders. I'm trying to see if its possible to segregate some tables based on gender.
To do this..I have also added another property "allowedstudentgender" which will decide students of which gender can sit in which table..

The changes in this code is shown below..

```
    var Table = function(id, name, students,maxstudents,allowedstudentgender) {
    this.students = ko.observableArray(students);
    this.students.id = id;
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.maxstudents=ko.observable(maxstudents);
    this.allowedstudentgender=ko.observableArray(allowedstudentgender);
};
```

And consecutive changes in the data:

```
 var initialTables = [
    new Table(1,"Table One",  [
       new Student(3, "Jim", "male"),
         new Student(6, "Chase", "male")
    ],2,["male"]),
    //and so on...
```

The original method which decides the number of students in each table is as below..

```
 this.isTableFull = function(parent) {
            return parent().length < self.maximumStudents;
        };
```

What I'm trying to figure out is **how to get the maxstudents property of the table** in this method..

Also.. To segregate users based on Gender, I need to change -verifyAssignments method..

The current functionality is checked by the following codepiece..

```
if (!ko.utils.arrayFirst(parent(), function(student) { return student.gender !== gender;})){// .... }
```

Here I need to figure out **how to get students gender mapped to tables' allowedstudentgender property**..

I tried to get the allowedstudentgender property by checking for 'arg.targetParent.allowedstudentgender' but it shows undefined

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `arg.targetParent` when placing a student is really the students array rather than the table that contains it, you can just move everything under it:

```
var Table = function(id, name, students,maxstudents,allowedstudentgender) {
  this.students = ko.observableArray(students);
  this.students.id = id;
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
  this.students.maxstudents=ko.observable(maxstudents);
  this.students.allowedstudentgender=ko.observableArray(allowedstudentgender);
};
```

then adjust any references to the new location and modify the handler for your new rules:

```
this.verifyAssignments = function(arg) {
    var parent = arg.targetParent;

    if (parent.id !== "Available Students" && parent.allowedstudentgender().length === 1 && arg.item.gender != parent.allowedstudentgender()[0]) {
        self.lastError("Cannot move " + arg.item.name() + " to " + arg.targetParent.id + " because the table is unigender.");
            arg.cancelDrop = true;
    }

};
```

[(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/q2s75geg/2/)

Comment: Thanks..just one thing.. In your solution, if I move a student from a table to available Students area.. visually the student moves but he does not in the masterlist or json below.. Could u just check that.. Also what is the difference in parent() and parent in isTableFull method?

Comment: For "available" the issue is that it is not a table so as we add properties it doesn't get them.. We could make it a table, keep repeating code, or add guards in accesses of these new properties. But the use of an external js on github makes it hard to do much now with the attack..  For parent vs parent(), parent.x is a normal property we added on to the observable's JS Object when creating the table, parent() is requesting the actual array through ko's official interface (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#reading-information-from-an-observablearray)

Comment: github seems to be responding again, so I tested adding the special check for available table as in the original example, and it seems to work.

Comment: that's gr8.. also you have added maxstudents and allowedstudentgender in students in Table method but in initialTables data, the sample data is being shown in prev schema, should I keep it as is or should that be changed as well to reciprocate Table method..

Comment: I wouldn't change initialTables to attach properties to the array since you need Table() to attach the properties once the ko observableArray is created and shouldn't count on it having any specific behavior for a base array with additional properties.. You may find it cleaner to pass all of the properties as one object for Table() to copy onto the ko object, but there are a lot of opinions on how to merge objects and whether to use various off topic libraries..