# Mapping hard coded data with server side generated data using knockout mapping

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

The code shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q2s75geg/2/) is an modified version of an example of knockout-sortable.js by RP Niemeyer and created by [lossleader](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269466/lossleader) as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328329/knockout-issue-with-accessing-a-nested-property/).

Here is a data model as follows..

```
var Table = function(id, name, students,maxstudents,allowedstudentgender) {
    this.students = ko.observableArray(students);
    this.students.id = id;
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.students.maxstudents=ko.observable(maxstudents);
    this.students.allowedstudentgender= ko.observableArray(allowedstudentgender);
};
```

The consecutive data is as follows..

```
    var initialTables = [
        new Table(1,"Table One",  [
           new Student(3, "Jim", "male"),
             new Student(6, "Chase", "male")
        ],2,["male"])
//and so on..
    ];
```

The data is initialised in the vm as follows..

```
var SeatingChartModel = function(tables, availableStudents) {
    var self = this;
    this.tables = ko.observableArray(tables);
```

But when the data is brought from the server and mapped to the knockout viewmodel using knockout-mapping.js.., what I do is something as follows..

```
    var SeatingChartModel = function() {
            var self = this;
            this.tables = ko.observableArray();
    // more stuff happens here..and then..

     $.get('/api/gettables', function (data) {
        self.tables(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)()); // for jtoken
              OR
        self.tables(ko.mapping.fromJS(JSON.parse(data))()); // for json
    };
```

I'm unable to figure out the necessary data structure of the json to be sent from server in this case..

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Try creating Data Transfer Objects and send an enumerable list of Tables. Each Table has properties the way they are required here. For students, try sending an array of strings/objects.

Comment: @chromio could you please state an example structure of the Table obj as I tried by adding a ko.tojson on tables, it does not even show id, maxstudents & allowedstudentgender. Unless I know the structure how do I send the data.., once I know I can send it across using DTO or something else as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using arraymap..

```
this.tables = ko.observableArray();
    var temptables= ko.utils.arrayMap(dataFromServer, function(item) {
    return new Table(item.id,item.name, item.students, item.maxstudents, item.allowedstudentgender);
        });
        this.tables(temptables);
```